# C++, Get handle to open process

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

I'm trying to get a handle to my open processes, this is what I've got:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Psapi.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    bool _result;
    DWORD *pProcessIds = new DWORD[1000];
    DWORD cb;
    DWORD *pBytesReturned= new DWORD[1000];
    _result =  EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000,pBytesReturned);

    HANDLE _Proccess = new HANDLE;

    for (int i = 0;i<=1000; i++)
    {
        _Proccess =   OpenProcess(READ_CONTROL,  false, *pProcessIds);
        DWORD error;
        error = GetLastError(); 
        CloseHandle(_Proccess);
        pProcessIds ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1- I am constanly getting error "87".

2- `_Proccess` isn't being assigned anything either. On every itertaion its being set at "0x00000000".

3- `EnumProcess` is working correctly because `pBytesReturned` returns a number.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `for (int i = 0;i<=1000; i++)` This is not the problem buy you do not want <= here since that will access 1 item past the end of your array.

Comment: `EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000,pBytesReturned);` 1000 is too small. You need 1000 * sizeof(DWORD) since the second parameter is defined as `The size of the pProcessIds array, in bytes.`

Comment: `DWORD *pBytesReturned= new DWORD[1000];` This is wrong as well. You do not create an array. This is a single pointer to a DWORD.  You read this DWORD to get the # of bytes returned. Make a DWORD variable and use & to get its address. Pass that as the 3rd parameter.

Comment: thanks for the info guys. Apparently it just stopped giving errors for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run as administrator

`for (int i = 0;i<=1000; i++)`
is wrong because you are missing the last iteration, change `<=` to `<`

`DWORD *pBytesReturned= new DWORD[1000];`
This can just be `DWORD bytesToReturn` instead of this dynamic array because you only need an integer return.

`EnumProcesses(pProcessIds, 1000,pBytesReturned);`
Instead of hardcoding 1000, use sizeof(array)

MSDN has a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) on how to do this properly.

I modified the code to do what you want it to do and tested it working:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.
    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, aProcesses[i]);
            CloseHandle(hProc);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```